# SBT library dependency on Github released JAR

Tags: github, sbt

I have a project on Github and I have set a release with a Jar for that project. I want to include this Jar in another project as an SBT dependency. How do I set up the resolvers to look for my jar in the github repo.

Answer (score 1):

You want to release your jar into a repository. One option I would recommend is [bintray](https://bintray.com/), see [bintray-sbt](https://github.com/softprops/bintray-sbt) which is an sbt plugin for publishing to bintray, and details how to setup your second project to fetch the publish artifact.